# Mismatch between input assembler and vertex shader - but it looks right

Tags: c++, shader, direct3d, hlsl

I had a similar issue someone kindly solved here, but that led me to this one.  The error is:

"Input Assembler - Vertex Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (SV_POSITION,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage."

Here is my declaration and the vertex shader input.  Can anyone tell me why they wouldn't match?  I'm stumped.

```
static const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexLayout[] =
{
    { "SV_POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0,  0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 16, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

...and the shader input:

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position             : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color                : COLOR;
};
```

Comment: Does it work if you use "POSITION" rather than "SV_POSITION"?

Comment: ``SV_POSITION`` works fine as long as it's consistent with the shader and the semantic...

Comment: Make sure you're binding the correct input-layout object to the input-assembler stage.

Comment: I think what Ross was suggesting was making sure that the input layout you are binding with ``IASetInputLayout`` is indeed exactly the same as the one you passed to ``CreateVertexShader``. If your shader isn't compatible with the layout, it should have failed at that point. In fact, make sure you are checking all ``HRESULT`` return values with ``if (FAILED(hr))`` or ``DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr)`` in case you are missing an error result somewhere.